# Left join is not working to retrieve random column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a MySQLi statement where I want to retrieve a random column (`url`) from a table called (`questions`). However, I don't want just any random `url`. This statement will depend on three conditions involving another table called `tracking`. `tracking` contains three columns (`user_id`, `q_id`, `answer`). So ultimately I want to retrieve all `urls` that haven't been answered yet by the user. For example, if the user has answered a question already then `tracking` will have something like this: `user_id: 2` `q_id: 2` `answer: 1` Now when we run this statement, `q_id: 2` should not be one of the random `urls`. It's also important to point out that `q_id` is also a primary key of `questions`.

I have tried this statement, but it's not working for some reason:

```
$values = $db->query("
SELECT url 
  FROM questions 
  LEFT 
  JOIN tracking
    ON tracking.user_id = '$id' 
   AND questions.q_id != tracking.q_id 
   AND tracking.answer != NULL 
 ORDER 
    BY rand() LIMIT 1
");
```

How can I make it so a random `url` is retrieved except for the questions that have already been answered by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you try to join on a not equals, so you will end up with an 1:n join, which doesn't work. (Not in this case).

Try something like this:

```
SELECT url FROM questions WHERE q_id NOT IN 
      (SELECT q_id FROM tracking WHERE user_id = $id 
      AND answer IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

And this is not a save way to insert variables into a Query, look at prepared statements:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Hmm, I am getting an error that states: `Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object` After the query I do: `$rows = $values->fetch_array();`

Comment: Test the query directly in your db enviroment (if possible), or at least the mysql error.
echo mysql_errno($db) . ": " . mysql_error($db) . "\n";

Comment: Hmm, it's working now, but the query is still giving a url that has already been answered for some reason...

Comment: Yes, I tried having two questions. I went and answered both questions, but the query is still displaying one of the two urls.

Comment: test the middel SQL (SELECT q_id FROM tracking WHERE user_id = '$id' 
      AND answer IS NOT NULL) and look if it returns both your answered questions (it should). If not look at your table, post your two rows here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133250/discussion-between-doktor-oswaldo-and-user2896120).